# Windows update by command line

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I'm looking for command line code to show the window below AND execute the link "Nach Updates suchen" (looking for updates). By **wuapp.exe** only the window is shown.

[image: Windows Update]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/351977/479081) work for you?

Comment: @benjamin: I tried it, also `C:\Windows\System32\wuauclt.exe /detectno`, but nothing seems to happen, no system feedback.

Comment: **%windir%\system32\wuauclt.exe /detectnow** you missed the w

Comment: @magicandre1981: Added "w" and admin rights but same result.